# Calculate running balance in mysql with view

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My simple table named ass_material with this columns:

```
mat_id    mat_name  supplier    request    stock_received   date 
1           alloy      test       30         0             feb13
2           alloy      test       30         10            feb14
3           alloy      test       30         20            feb14
```

How can I generate it or calculate it as:
It will also generate a 'complete' status when stock_balance and request matches.

```
  mat_id    mat_name  supplier    request    stock_received  Stock_balance   date    status
    1           alloy      test       30         0                 0        feb13
    2           alloy      test       30         10               10        feb14
    3           alloy      test       30         20               30        feb14   complete
```

here's my reference code from my other view:
how can i tweak this into my desired output above?

```
SELECT m.`mat_id`, m.`mat_name`, m.`request`, m.`stock_receieved`,
       (select sum(stock_received) - sum(stock_received)
        from material m2
        where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
              m2.mat_id <= m.mat_id
       ) as Stock_balance,
      m.`date`,
      s.`sup_name`
FROM `material` m
LEFT JOIN `supplier` s on s.sup_id = m.supplier_id
ORDER BY m.`mat_id` ASC;
```

Comment: How did you solve for stock balance?

Comment: when stocks are received it will total the previous stock_received into the stock_balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `stock_balance` is just the sum of `stock_received`, then use that in the subquery:

```
SELECT m.`mat_id`, m.`mat_name`, m.`request`, m.`stock_receieved`,
       (select sum(stock_received)
        from material m2
        where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
              m2.mat_id <= m.mat_id
       ) as Stock_balance,
       (case when (select sum(stock_received)
                   from material m2
                   where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
                         m2.mat_id <= m.mat_id
                  ) = request
             then 'Complete'
             else 'Incomplete'
        end) as status,
      m.`date`,
      s.`sup_name`
FROM `material` m LEFT JOIN
     `supplier` s
     on s.sup_id = m.supplier_id
ORDER BY m.`mat_id` ASC;
```

Comment: thanks sir.. but how can i add 'complete' as status when stock_balance will equal into the request quantity?

Comment: @user3117337 . . . In a view-compatible statement, you have to repeat the subquery as above.

Comment: Thanks sir it's working.. Can I ask one more?.. How can I add another case when request = 0 then status = '' ?

Comment: @user3117337 . . . Just add `when request = 0 then ''` to the second `case` statement.

Comment: is this correct sir?       `(case when (select sum(stock_received)
                   from genmaterial m2
                   where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
                         m2.genmat_id <= m.genmat_id
                  ) = req_qty
             then 'Complete'
    (case when (select sum(stock_received)
                   from genmaterial m2
                   where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
                         m2.genmat_id <= m.genmat_id
                  ) = 0
             else ''
    else 'Incomplete'
        end) as status `

Comment: sir @Gordon Linoff I need your help... please see my new question.
[New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772554/complicated-select-query-for-inventory)