# Complicated Select query for inventory

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have my select code:

```
SELECT m.`genmat_id`,m.`mat_type`,m.`mat_name`, m.`category`, m.`size`, m.`req_qty`, m.`stock_received`,  m.`stock_released`,   m.`release_approval`, 
       (select sum(stock_received) - sum(stock_released)
        from genmaterial m2
        where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
              m2.genmat_id <= m.genmat_id
       ) as Stock_balance,
       (case when (select sum(stock_received)
                   from genmaterial m2
                   where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
                         m2.genmat_id <= m.genmat_id

                  ) = req_qty
             then 'Complete'
             when req_qty = 0 then ''
             else 'Incomplete'
        end) as status,
      m.`date`,
      s.`sup_name`
FROM `genmaterial` m LEFT JOIN
     `supplier` s
     on s.sup_id = m.sup_id

ORDER BY m.`genmat_id` ASC
```

OUTPUT(disregard the Full Texts column):

```
Full Texts  genmat_id   mat_type    mat_name    category    size    req_qty stock_received  stock_released  release_approval    Stock_balance   status           date   sup_name
    Edit    Delete  69  pur aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       0                  0                                 0           Incomplete   2014-02-14  E-store 
    Edit    Delete  70  Raw aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       50                 0                                 50          Incomplete   2014-02-15  E-store
    Edit    Delete  71  Raw aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       80                 0                                 130         Complete     2014-02-20  E-store
    Edit    Delete  72  pur mild steel          metal       100 m   50        0                  0                                 0           Incomplete   2014-02-13  Handy Shop
    Edit    Delete  73  Raw mild steel          metal       100 m   50        50                 0                                 50          Complete     2014-02-15  Handy Shop
    Edit    Delete  74  pur mild steel          metal       100 m   40        0                  0                                 50          Incomplete   2014-02-14  E-store
    Edit    Delete  77  Raw mild steel          metal       100 m   40        40                 0                                 90          Incomplete   2014-02-17  E-store
```

The mat_id 74 is a new request identified by `mat_type = pur`
and the mat_id 77 is the receiving of the request with 40 on stock_received and `mat_type = Raw`. Now, the stock_balance is just so right because it Sums up the previous total of the `material + the stock_received`.

My question: How can I make the status complete 
with this condition?

it will sum up the stock_received when `mat_type=raw` inside a counter
and if the `counter=req_qty` will have the `status=complete`
My existing code generates a status when `Stock_balance = req_qty`.
How can I do it `counter = req_qty`
and the stock_balance is from the sum of counter every mat_name
also the stock_balance - stock_released(stock_out)

like(see counter column):
The counter will only count the stock_received per new mat_type=pur

```
Full Texts  genmat_id   mat_type    mat_name    category    size    req_qty stock_received    counter     stock_released    release_approval    Stock_balance   status           date   sup_name
    Edit    Delete  69  pur aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       0                  0              0                                  0           Incomplete   2014-02-14  E-store 
    Edit    Delete  70  Raw aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       50                 50             0                                  50          Incomplete   2014-02-15  E-store
    Edit    Delete  71  Raw aluminum flat bar   metal       100 m   130       80                 130            0                                  130         Complete     2014-02-20  E-store
    Edit    Delete  72  pur mild steel          metal       100 m   50        0                  0              0                                  0           Incomplete   2014-02-13  Handy Shop
    Edit    Delete  73  Raw mild steel          metal       100 m   50        50                 50             0                                  50          Complete     2014-02-15  Handy Shop
    Edit    Delete  74  pur mild steel          metal       100 m   40        0                  0              0                                  50          Incomplete   2014-02-14  E-store
    Edit    Delete  77  Raw mild steel          metal       100 m   40        40                 40             0                                  90          Incomplete   2014-02-17  E-store
```